# kivy: resizing ellipse not working

Tags: kivy

I am trying to resize an ellipse. But regardless of what size I set it to, the circle always looks like this:
[image]

My Python code:

```
class TestCircle(Widget):
    def move(self, dt):
        self.x = self.x + self.velocity_x

sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(WelcomeScreen(name='welcome'))

class ShootingApp(App):
    def play_ball(self, intensity, duration):
        ball = TestCircle()
        ball.size = Vector(50, 50)
        ball.pos = Vector(0,0)
        basicscreen3.add_widget(ball)

    def build(self):
        return sm
```

My kivy code is this:

```
<TestCircle>:
    size: 50, 50
    canvas:
        Color: 
            rgb: (0, 1, 1)
        Ellipse:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to set the size of the TestCircle? This doesn't do anything because its parent, basicscreen3, is presumably a Screen and therefore a RelativeLayout that automatically positions children to fill itself.

If you don't want a layout to set the size of your widgets, you should add `size_hint: None, None` as well as trying to set a manual size.